# Text sizing in android with java and libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating text in libgx, but am having a problem where the text can be different sizes depending on the phone. for the images, I resize them based on the screen size, but I can't do this with the text,b ecuase it needs wrapping and fitting to the phone. Can anyone advise on a better way of drawing text that looks the same on any mobile screen.

The text class:

```
public class TextActor extends Actor {
BitmapFont font;
String text;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float w = 10;
float h = 10;

public TextActor(String text){
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"));
    this.text = text;
}

@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    font.draw(batch, text, x, y);
}

public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
    this.x =x;
    this.y=y;
}

public void setText(String text){
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

in the screen class:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true);
    scoreText = new TextActor("How to play: \n");
    scoreText.setPosition(10, ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() /7) * 7));
    stage.addActor(scoreText);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my project I used different font sizes for different phones like this:

```
// create fonts
        float density = Gdx.graphics.getDensity();

        String path = "hdpi";
        if (density <= 1) {
            path = "mdpi";
        } else if (density > 1 && density < 1.5f) {
            path = "hdpi";
        } else if (density >= 1.5 && density < 2) {
            path = "xdpi";
        } else if (density >= 2) {
            path = "xxdpi";
        }

        normalFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/" + path + "/font.fnt"));
```

As you can see I used bitmapfont, you can find a bitmapfont creator here with you can create different size of bitmapfonts: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1247 . This way you can work with the fonts like you worked with your resized bitmaps, and also you can resize the font like:

```
normalFont.setScale(2.0f);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextBounds like:

textBounds = yourfont.getBounds("How to play: \n");
then get the width of textbounds like: textbounds.width.
then position where you want.

Comment: Okay, that's getting the width. How would i set the width to that of the screen, then set the height to the correct proportions for the text